# how to remove original user who created google-play-console account

Tags: google-play-console, google-console-developer

I've a google play console account. First I created using one Gmail and I invited to the second email with full permision and It looks like below image now.

First row -> secondly invited email
Second row-> original email

[image]

Now I need to give full permission to email2 and completely remove the originally created email from this account and use only the secondly invited one.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to request a transfer of ownership of the developer account to Google Developer support.

See https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en-GB for the restrictions.